# How to order a bootstrap-treeview according to node id

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-treeview

When I send my JSON data (an ordered query) to a bootstrap treeview menu, the data is re-ordered according to the menu's node-names.

I want the menu nodes ordered according to my JSON structure. Is that possible?

I changed code sctructure and plugin as well.

Thank You.

Comment: Show us your code so we have an idea what you're talking about.